# Disable options on select2 after specific one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using a select2 in my web site with 10 options let's say. So I have this js:

```
$("#myselect").select2({ 
    maximumSelectionLength: 3
});
```

When the option 1 is selected I want to disable all the other options on the Select2. Somehow like skip the maximumSelectionLength and suddenly allow only one to be selected. But this should happen only if I select the option 1.

If I choose the option 2 for example I just need to deactivate the option 1.

So in general the option 1 needs to be excluded from the max of 3 selection if something else is selected, and should deactivate all the other options in case it is selected in the beginning. I hope I make it quite clear in the description.

Is something like this possible and how?

I tried this one>

```
if($("#myselect").val() == 1){
    $("#myselect").find("option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != 1){
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

and this actually adds the disabled attribute to all the option when the option 1 is selected, but not on the produced select2 html code, only on my initial html, so it does not actually work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update the select2 initialization after adding the disable attribute. Try `$("#myselect").select2("updateResults")`

Comment: Is this 'updateResults' an option of select2? Because it does not seem to work.

Comment: check select2 plugin's documentation. Basically you will have to reinitialize or call some update function of the plugin, as you have updated the structure if the select.

Comment: Actually this one works. I just have to trigger a change     $("#myselect").select2({maximumSelectionLength: 3}).trigger('selection:update');

Answer (score 1):

Well after @karan3112 recommendation I added this one

```
   $("#myselect").select2({maximumSelectionLength:3}).trigger('selection:update');
```

after adding the disabled attributed and works just fine.